# MySQL Replication Logs Filling Partition

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

We have MySQL replication setup from site-to-site. The slave is just a backup used for reporting etc(No write). Everything is going well as far as I can tell.

However, the server is quickly running out of space on the partition mysql replication logs to.

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 
                  Master_User: 
                  Master_Port: 
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000006
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 43158527
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000015
                Relay_Log_Pos: 43158672
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000006
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: mysql
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 43158527
              Relay_Log_Space: 43158870
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
```

Here is where the confusion comes in. I want to implement expire_logs_days to 3 days or so...

However I am afraid of breaking replication because;

Master_log_file = 006 and it's date is Nov 18.

```
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  20K Nov  3 15:36 mysql-bin.000001
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 748K Nov  3 15:36 mysql-bin.000002
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 1.1G Nov 18 09:06 mysql-bin.000003
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 216M Nov 18 09:22 mysql-bin.000004
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  125 Nov 18 09:39 mysql-bin.000005
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 1.1G Nov 18 11:34 mysql-bin.000006
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 1.1G Nov 18 11:41 mysql-bin.000007
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 1.1G Nov 18 14:23 mysql-bin.000008
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 1.1G Nov 18 14:29 mysql-bin.000009
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 1.1G Nov 19 08:57 mysql-bin.000010
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 366M Nov 20 09:37 mysql-bin.000011
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  60M Nov 20 12:09 mysql-bin.000012
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  23K Nov 20 12:10 mysql-bin.000013
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 1.1G Nov 23 00:43 mysql-bin.000014
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 1.1G Nov 26 12:03 mysql-bin.000015
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 251M Nov 27 11:33 mysql-bin.000016
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  304 Nov 26 12:03 mysql-bin.index
```

**Questions**

- Do I need to set a higher days threshold for log file expiry?
- IE; will "SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days = 3;" break my replication
  because mysql-bin.000006 is the current master_log_file?
- Perhaps setting the log file size limit lower in addition to expiry
  is a solution?

I've looked into these for the original idea but I want to be 100% sure:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41050/is-it-safe-to-delete-mysql-bin-files
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-administration-status.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at your slave's own binary logs.
Your slave has clearly the `log_bin` variable set, and it's filling its disks with it's own binary logs (not the master's logs, their names probably contain a `relay` word, since you are using defaults in binary and relay log names). You can view them with `show master status`. To solve this problem (if you don't have any slaves attached to this slave) you can set the `log_bin` variable to OFF. Yup, you can also set the `expire_logs_days` variable on slave and it won't break anything (because it controls binary logs expiration date on a server it's configured on) but in case you don't need them at all - why keep 'em ?

Comment: Thanks for this! I was wrong with the way I thought replication worked! You are spot on, there is indeed relay logs. Perfect answer. I would upvote but I cant :(